# AccessToken does not get invalid - Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, authentication, authorization, access-token, spring-oauth2

i set up spring oauth in my project and authentication seems to work. After testing using `PostMan` i saw that the `AccessToken` **can be used even after beeing expired**...it does not get invalid and the user can still use it to get resources.

I tested this by setting the expiration time of `AccessToken` to 2 seconds.

Here is some code of my configuration:

**POM.xml**:

```
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>   
...
```

**AuthorizationServerConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
@Autowired

private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;
@Autowired
private DbConfig dbConfig;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JdbcTokenStoreImpl(dbConfig.dataSource());
}

@Bean
public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
    return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
}

@Autowired
public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, DbConfig dbConfig) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.dbConfig = dbConfig;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);

}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dbConfig.dataSource());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetai

lsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

**ServerSecurityConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
@Import(Encoders.class)
public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
    }
}
```

The `UserDetailsService` etc. I also have configured, but I thing they are not relevant for investigating this Problem. The Problem is more related to the `AccessToken` itself and not in getting one.

Is this Problem maybe related to the fact that I am using `Spring 3.0.0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to migrate an "old" spring-boot app to the new release ?

Since many months, "spring-security-oauth" is no longer supported. See https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth

All oauth2 stuff is available in spring-security-oauth2-server library / spring boot autoconfiguration.
Try to remove your dependency, add spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server.
Check if your context has a "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri" property, value is a jwks ressource with keys used to signed bearer token.

Now, Let spring-boot autoconfigure your context. Bearer token is validated with a OAuth2TokenValidator, default implementation only checks that expiration is not null. Then bearer token is authenticated and use a JwtDecoder to do so.
"spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri" triggers creation of a JwtDecoder with Nimbus library at start-up. This implementation checks the expiration (see OAuth2ResourceServerJwtConfiguration spring-boot configuration).
(Generate a 401 response).

You can also provide your own JwtDecoder and check expiration or others jwt claims checks.

I Hope it is clear enought :)

Comment: could be...I just descided to switch to firbase Auth...because spent days on this...